# Jquery store values from array

Tags: php, jquery

```
success: function (response) {
                    for (var i in response)
                    {
                        var serialized_data = '['+response[i].position+']';
                        alert(serialized_data);

                    }
                }
```

Result of serialized_data = [{"x": 0, "y": 0, "width": 2, "height": 2}]

Data is getting from table via jquery ajax and stored in a variable.
How can I get data of x,y,width and height in jquery? Could you please help me to find a solution?

Comment: `data[0].x`, `data[0].y`, `data[0].width`, `data[0].height`

Comment: @Viral Thanks for your quick reply. I have updated my response code and results could you please check.

Answer (score 0):

Use Following process to get values

```
$.each(eval(response),function(i,item)
{
    var x=item.x;
    var y=item.y;
    var width=item.width;
    var height=item.height;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you support. I got the result.

```
success: function (response) {
                    for (var i in response)
                    {
                        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( response[i].position );
                        var x   = obj.x;
                        var y   = obj.y;
                        var width = obj.width;
                        var height = obj.height;
                    }
                }
```